# Delete image from images folder with php

Tags: php, image, delete-file

I am creating simple blog and deleting post from database but I want to delete image posted with that post I have did some code for deleting post from database but need help to delete image with that specific post.

This is my Delete_post.php it's working fine to delete post from database help expected to delete image:

```php
<?php 
        include("includes/Config.php");

        if(isset($_GET['delete_post'])){

        $delete_id = $_GET['delete_post'];

        $delete_post = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id='$delete_id' ";

        $run_delete = mysql_query($delete_post);


        echo "<script>alert('Post Has Been Deleted')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('../view_all_post.php','_self')</script>";
    }
?>
```

This is what I tried to use:

```php
<?php 
        include("includes/Config.php");

        if(isset($_GET['delete_post'])){

        $delete_id = $_GET['delete_post'];

        $img_d = $_GET['img_id'];

        unlink("../../post_imgs/$img_d");

        $delete_post = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id='$delete_id' ";

        $run_delete = mysql_query($delete_post);


        echo "<script>alert('Post Has Been Deleted')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('../view_all_post.php','_self')</script>";
    }
?>
```

[image]

Comment: And your question is? You can delete files in PHP via [`unlink()`](http://php.net/unlink)

Comment: you look for unlink()

Comment: yes i tried unlink but it's not working

Comment: @Shaggy Then it's up to you to tell the people who have given you answers below, that what you tried did not work. You also need to check for errors and use tools such as `var_dump()` to see what is being passed or not.

Comment: @fred-ii- thanks for your tip now everything is working fine ... :)

Comment: You know that, Stack lets you put in your own answer as to how you fixed it. The choice is yours ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove files using `unlink()` in PHP

```
unlink('file path');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the name of that file (best to have full path) just use `unlink()`, follow documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php